# Rails, active storage, Error message when I try to attach a photo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, activerecord, rails-activestorage, seed

I am trying to attach a photo to instances in the `seed.rb` directly. But I don't think that is the issue, because it doesn't work in the console either.
When I run `rails db:seed` I get this error message:
`Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ../app/assets/images/image.jpg`

Here is my Model:

```
class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
  restaurant_types = ["chinese", "italian", "japanese", "french", "belgian"]
  has_one_attached :photo
  has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
  validates :name, :address, :category, :phone_number, presence: true
  validates :category, inclusion: { in: restaurant_types, message: "%{value} is not a valid size" }
end
```

Here is my seed file:

```
require 'open-uri'
require "faker"
puts "deleting all restaurants and reviews"

Review.delete_all
Restaurant.delete_all

puts Restaurant.count
puts Review.count

puts "creating new restaurants"

20.times do
  name = Faker::Restaurant.name
  address = Faker::Address.community
  phone = Faker::PhoneNumber.cell_phone
  category = ["chinese", "italian", "japanese", "french", "belgian"].sample
  restaurant = Restaurant.create(name: name, address: address, phone_number: phone, category: category)
  restaurant.photo.attach(io: File.open('../app/assets/images/image.jpg'), filename: 'image')
end
```

And I also included `require "active_storage/engine"` in my `config/application.rb` file.

And here is my application folder and where both my seed.rb and image.jpg files are located. Apparently there is something wrong with the link?

[image]

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the path of your application by `Rails.root`

change to this in your seed file and try

```
restaurant.photo.attach(io: File.open(Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "images", "image.jpg")), filename: 'image.jpg')
```

You can store this in a variable also

```
file_path = Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "images", "image.jpg")
restaurant.photo.attach(io: File.open(filepath), filename: 'image.jpg')
```

Also, add a condition for file exist

```
File.exist? file_path
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply. But I actually found what was wrong. My ```storgage.yml``` file was missing, and also a gem. I will post the solution in a bit, maybe it will be helpful to somebody esle! Thanks again!

Comment: Actually you are right! In the meantime I forgot I was fetching images from my server and not directly from the images folder within the app. I just tried your solution and it worked! Thank you so much :)